# Regex html get attribute with specific attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to get an attribute valu from a html tag with another specific attribute.

```
<label attr1 attr2="test"> -> test
<label attr1 attr2='test'> -> test
<label attr2="test" attr1> -> test
<label attr2='test' attr1> -> test
<label attr1
  attr2="test"> -> test
<label attr1 
  attr2='test'> -> test
<label 
  attr2="test" attr1> -> test
<label 
  attr2='test' attr1> -> test
<label attr2='test'> -> Not match
<label attr2="test"> -> Not match
```

Comment: Don't use regex here, use JavaScript, which is also a DOM/HTML parser.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have stream with html format.

Comment: Use a real HTML parser.  RegEx is nothing but trouble for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
var attrRegExp = /<(?=[^>]+attr1)[^>]+attr2=["']([^"']+)/ig;
var match = attrRegExp.exec(text);
while (match != null) {
    // capturing group 1: match[1]
    match = attrRegExp.exec(text);
}
```

This will loop through all of your HTML and the attribute in question will be in match[1]. You could push all matches to an array, for example.